# index.html подключает `styles.less` вместо `styles.css`

Tags: css, less

почему у меня сменилось `styles.css` на `styles.less` ( недел. назад было все на css?)
Код правила в нетбинсе, он автоматически перекомпилирует `less` файлы в `css` файлы.
Файл `index.html` подключает только css файлы. Как исправить?

Так не бывает, скиншот прилагаю, неделю назад все было на css...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Вот так я делаю в нетбинсе. Сначала делаю верстку. Заходим в свойства пректа, выбираем предпроцессоры СSS->Далее по цепочке (см. скриншот). Когда у меня папка /www/css перекомпилирутся, я ее копирую и вставляю в проект.(но там у меня подключается к несуществующему /src/less/)...Раньше я работала точно также, и у меня всегда подключались css файлы и верстке, и в проекте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что старым браузером пользовался. Оно показывает в каком именно файле находится стиль. Удобно же, легко найти в случае если надо поменять. Файл у тебя подключен css. А в инспекторе показывает в каком less файле ты можешь найти свой стиль.И зачем исправлять? Стили не показываются? Или верстка полетела то? ничего же не должно было поменятся.

Comment: Видимо, вы добавили sourcemaps к вашему коду во время сборки.

Comment: @Moonvvell, я использую chrome Версия 59.0.3047.4 dev (в обновлениях не нуждается). По поводу "зачем исправлять", у меня на конечном проекте (wordpress) less не используется. Мне нужно было сделать правки сначала в верстке для less, чтобы less файлы скомпилировать для папки css, отсюда взять папку css и вставить в проект wordpress. (кстати, в проекте wordpress  нет никаких файлов less, там тоже css, однако в браузере подсвечивается less c путем, как в верстке, а в самом проекте нет такого пути)...

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, и что надо сделать, убрать все файлы в папке сss c расширением .css.map . А как же компилироваться будет? Или что-то я не понимаю, что надо сделать?

Comment: @Flambo покажите каким образом вы собираете ваши стили (таск галп, или грант, или что там у вас).

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, спасибо огромное... Помогите, пож-ста. Вопрос обновила.

Comment: Уберите галочку "сгенерировать дополнительную информацию".

Comment: Просто выложите ваши файлы .less на сервер в те места где их ищет браузер. Вам же будет удобнее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, то есть в самом проекте  (не верстке) подключать less файлы? Так понять?

Comment: И в проекте тоже.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, не работает так , не компилируется... правильно, но компиляция выполняется.

Comment: Просто выложите ваши файлы .less на сервер в те места где их ищет браузер. Вам же будет удобнее.
Какое удобство? А поняла, просто компилировать в проекте, а не в самой верстке... Спасибо. Как я не догадалась.